# boost serialization error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

So I tried to serialize my classes using boost::serialization recently and was reading this tutorial: http://en.highscore.de/cpp/boost/serialization.html.
I can compile the codes in this page but I cant compile the codes that I wrote myself. for example in the section "Serialization of class hierarchy objects" we have this code:

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream> 
#include <string> 

std::stringstream ss; 

class person 
{ 
public: 
  person() 
  { 
  } 

  person(int age) 
    : age_(age) 
  { 
  } 

  int age() const 
  { 
    return age_; 
  } 

private: 
  friend class boost::serialization::access; 

  template <typename Archive> 
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) 
  { 
    ar & age_; 
  } 

  int age_; 
}; 

class developer 
  : public person 
{ 
public: 
  developer() 
  { 
  } 

  developer(int age, const std::string &language) 
    : person(age), language_(language) 
  { 
  } 

  std::string language() const 
  { 
    return language_; 
  } 

private: 
  friend class boost::serialization::access; 

  template <typename Archive> 
  void serialize(Archive &ar, const unsigned int version) 
  { 
    ar & boost::serialization::base_object<person>(*this); 
    ar & language_; 
  } 

  std::string language_; 
}; 

void save() 
{ 
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss); 
  developer d(31, "C++"); 
  oa << d; 
} 

void load() 
{ 
  boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ss); 
  developer d; 
  ia >> d; 
  std::cout << d.age() << std::endl; 
  std::cout << d.language() << std::endl; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
  save(); 
  load(); 
}
```

And it works fine, but lets say I wrote this code:

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp> 
#include <string> 

class A
{
   friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
   std::string a;
private:
   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int version)
   {
        archive & a;
   }
};

class B : public A
{
   friend class boost::serialization::access;
public:
   std::string b;
private:
   template<class Archive>
   void serialize(Archive& archive, const unsigned int version)
   {
        archive & boost::serialization::base_object<A>(*this);
        archive & b;
   }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(B) 

void save() 
{ 
  std::ofstream file("archive.xml"); 
  boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(file); 
  B *myB = new B();
  myB->a = "1";
  myB->a = "2";

  oa << myB; 
  delete myB;
  file.close();
} 

void load() 
{ 
  std::ifstream file("archive.xml"); 
  boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(file); 
  A *myB;

  ia >> myB;
  std::cout << myB->a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   save();
   load();
   std::cin.get();
}
```

when I compile this, I get this error:

```
error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type  c:\program files\boost_1_55_0\boost\mpl\print.hpp
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Today I Learned: if MSVC gives a `error C4308` toplevel error, this might well indicate a `BOOST_STATIC_WARNING` was triggered in a template instantiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>miffed by the compile error (also currently don't have MSVC handy to try).</strike>

At the end of the day I was able to test with MSVC2013. The full error (warning) reads:

```
boost_1_55_0\boost\mpl\print.hpp(51): warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type
          boost_1_55_0\boost\serialization\static_warning.hpp(92) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::print<boost::serialization::BOOST_SERIALIZATION_STATIC_WARNING_LINE<137>>' being compiled
          boost_1_55_0\boost\serialization\export.hpp(137) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::serialization::static_warning_test<false,137>' being compiled
          boost_1_55_0\boost\serialization\export.hpp(136) : while compiling class template member function 'const boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::guid_initializer<B> &boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::guid_initializer<B>::export_guid(void) const'
          so.cpp(40) : see reference to function template instantiation 'const boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::guid_initializer<B> &boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::guid_initializer<B>::export_guid(void) const' being compiled
          so\so.cpp(40) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::archive::detail::extra_detail::guid_initializer<B>' being compiled
```

The line in `export.hpp` reads:

```
    BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(boost::is_polymorphic< T >::value);
```

There you go, you're trying to serialize a polymorphic class through a poitner-to-base, and that does not make sense unless RTTI is available. For this to be true, the class needs at least 1 virtual method.

---

Fixing up the sample so it works:

I note the lack of NVP wrappers. Here's a compiling version: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a69e87e4f26a9317)**

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <string>

class A {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

  public:
    std::string a;
    virtual ~A() {}

  private:
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        archive &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
    }
};

class B : public A {
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

  public:
    std::string b;

  private:
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &archive, const unsigned int version)
    {
        using namespace boost::serialization;
        archive &make_nvp("base", base_object<A>(*this));
        archive &BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);
    }
};

BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT(B)

void save()
{
    std::ofstream file("archive.xml", std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(file);
    B *myB = new B();
    myB->a = "1";
    myB->b = "2";

    A* myA = myB;
    oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("myA", myA);
    delete myB;
    file.close();
}

void load()
{
    std::ifstream file("archive.xml", std::ios::binary);
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(file);
    A *myA;

    ia >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("myA", myA);

    std::cout << "a: " << myA->a << std::endl;
    if (B* myB = dynamic_cast<B*>(myA))
        std::cout << "b: " << myB->b << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    save();
    load();
}
```

Note that you needed (as well) to serialize the same type (`A*`) as you were deserializing.

By making `A` a virtual class, you can use a runtime cast:

```
    std::cout << "a: " << myA->a << std::endl;
    if (B* myB = dynamic_cast<B*>(myA))
        std::cout << "b: " << myB->b << std::endl;
```

For completeness, here's the corresponding `archive.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="10">
<myA class_id="1" class_name="B" tracking_level="1" version="0" object_id="_0">
    <base class_id="0" tracking_level="1" version="0" object_id="_1">
        <a>1</a>
    </base>
    <b>2</b>
</myA>
```

Comment: Wow, this worked! But I'm having difficulty understanding this, what is the difference that makes this work but not the one I wrote? Is it because of making nvp or the virtual class? Why compiler couldn't compile the code I wrote?

Comment: Because XML needs element names for the serialized nodes (see **[docs for "Wrappers"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#nvp)**). Also, there was incongruence where you serialized a `B*` but tried to deserialize as `A*` (that was not a compile-time issue, though)

Comment: Seems that it is because of the virtual class, if I comment the virtual deconstructor and use static_cast instead of dynamic_cast the error appears again! So, should all of my classes be virtual? why?? Isn't this absurd?

Comment: @sinaTavakoli Not at all. Reading error messages is important. That was not **nearly** the same error. Also, your original code didn't even have the `dynamic_cast<>`. It's what I added to make it more clear that the `myA` serialization still does correctly deserialize as a dynamic `B` instance.

Comment: And no, this isn't absurd. What's making it seem "absurd" is not _reasoning_ about things in a rational way.

Comment: @ sehe it was exactly the same error!
error C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type.
Thank you for your help, I learned something from you, but I think it is better to get the facts straight before judging about the "rationality" of someone! Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @sinaTavakoli Ah. If you randomly replace `dynamic_cast<>` with `static_cast<>` you should get interesting errors. Obviously, `static_cast<>` can only work between pointers of statically known, related types. (Still, I don't see how it would give `C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type`.) And since `dynamic_cast<>` requires RTTI and RTTI is only specified for virtual types... there's the need for `virtual` destructor. So, no, it's not absurd you need to have a virtual type. You are the one _using_ it as a virtual type, so that's the reason you need it :)

Comment: @sinaTavakoli Incidentally I have now been able to try the code on MSVC2013, and indeed I can reproduce your error. When you trace up the template instatiation stack, you will find the `BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(boost::is_polymorphic<T>::value)` which was intended to explain precisely that your type needs to be polymorphic to be able to serialize through a polymorphic pointer-to-base. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Alright, it makes sense. So I have to have at least one virtual function to make it work. And there is no other way?

Comment: You could pass the concrete type separately and use it to instantiate the desired type in a custom `load` method. I think storing a `boost::variant<A,B>` would be most natural for this. This implied you don't require runtime polymorphic behaviour from your classes. If you somehow _require_ both (???) you could layer on type erasure. But we're getting a bit adrift. I'd do the simplest thing. If `B` is - a `A` and your instances could dynamically be either of the two, virtual polymorphism is the natural match with no immediately apparent downsides.

Comment: Alright, it is decided then, I'll go with the virtual polymorphism one and save the trouble, thanks for your time mate ;)

Comment: Actually, in retrospect looks more like the original error, although also C4308, was actually triggered from `oa << (*this)` - which traces back to this check: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8802107/